# Update data from two Data Frames Scala-Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two Data Frames:

```
DF1:
    ID | Col1 | Col2
    1    a      aa 
    2    b      bb
    3    c      cc

DF2:
    ID | Col1 | Col2
    1    ab      aa 
    2    b       bba
    4    d       dd
```

How can I join these two DFs and the result should be:

```
Result:
        1    ab      aa 
        2    b       bba
        3    c       cc
        4    d       dd
```

My code is:

```
val df = DF1.join(DF2, Seq("ID"), "outer")
        .select($"ID",
          when(DF1("Col1").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(DF1("Col1")).as("Col1"),
          when(DF1("Col2").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(DF2("Col2")).as("Col2"))
            .orderBy("ID")
```

And it works, but I don't want to specify each column, because I have large files.
So, is there any way to update the dataframe (and to add some recors if in the second DF are new one) without specifying each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `leftanti` join of `df1` with `df2` and *merging* of the *result* into `df2` should get your desired output as

```
df2.union(df1.join(df2, Seq("ID"), "leftanti")).orderBy("ID").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+----+
|ID |Col1|Col2|
+---+----+----+
|1  |ab  |aa  |
|2  |b   |bba |
|3  |c   |cc  |
|4  |d   |dd  |
+---+----+----+
```

**The solution doesn't match the logic you have in your code but generates the expected result**